# why autorun doesnt work with my application?

Tags: windows, autorun

I wrote a C# app with autorun feature. It successfully writes a registry key to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and application appears in the task manager (and Sysinternals autoruns), but the application doesn't start after user logon, while others do.

*P.S.: Adding it to the task scheduler, placing shortcut to `autorun` folder, or .bat tricks are not the solution*

Comment: thanks. yes, I'm better in c# than in english.
maybe https://english.stackexchange.com/ will be interesting for you :)

Comment: Unfortunately my original comment seems to have been removed, so nobody knows, what the context is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is create key in HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
seems 64-bit windows autorun mechanism is not able to start 32-bit apps if they not "declared" as 32-bit

*it will be nice if someone post here link to short documentation how windows process autorun (order, error handling etc)*